# Replace host key automatically on linux

Tags: perl, sftp

I have a script that connects to an SFTP server with the following code:

```
use Net::SFTP::Foreign;
my %cfg = (
    user        => "$user", 
    password    => "$password",
    port        => 22,
    more        => [-o => 'StrictHostKeyChecking no']
);
my $sftp = Net::SFTP::Foreign->new("$host",%cfg);
```

I am using StrictHostKeyChecking to make sure the script automatically accepts the ssh key.
The issue begins when the server replaces the host key with new one. I get the error: WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!

So I have to manually remove the key by running **ssh-keygen -R testserver.com**
After that the script works fine again.
I am trying to find a way to autmatically replace the key if it changes.
Technically I can run **ssh-keygen -R testserver.com** every time the script runs, but I do not like that solution.
So far I am not able to a good automated way to replace the key.

Comment: Perhaps `StrictHostKeyChecking=no` https://askubuntu.com/a/167753/422764

Comment: I believe it works without equal too: http://search.cpan.org/dist/Net-SFTP-Foreign/lib/Net/SFTP/Foreign.pm

Comment: The does add the key automatically on the initial run. it only fails of there is already the key in the known_hosts file and server is providing a different key.

Comment: Symlink known_hosts to /dev/null ;)

Comment: @Сухой27 looks like this was the correct solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add another option that points UserKnownHostsFile to /dev/null should do the trick, not that it's recommend from security perspective ;-)

```
use Net::SFTP::Foreign;
my %cfg = (
    user        => "$user", 
    password    => "$password",
    port        => 22,
    more        => [-o => 'StrictHostKeyChecking=no',
                    -o => 'UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null']
);
my $sftp = Net::SFTP::Foreign->new("$host",%cfg);
```